# Select Distinct value from column and return all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select distinct value from a column but return all rows related to the values selected. In psuedo code it will look like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE field is Distinct
```

I googled the question and I've tried using GROUP BY but the query never executes. Thanks for the help.

I am using a Microsoft SQL Database.

The Data looks like this:

```
CodeId   Code   CatalogType    CodeGroup  CodeText  CodeGroupText  CodeDesc  State_ID
-------  -----  -------------  ---------- --------  -------------- --------- ---------
1        AAAA    1             100         Plastic   Plastic Center  NULL      2
2        BBBB    1             100         Glass     Glass Center    NULL      2
3        CCCC    1             101         Steel     Steel Center    NULL      2
```

I just want to the data to look the same just where the code group is distinct.

Data would look like this:

```
CodeId   Code   CatalogType    CodeGroup  CodeText  CodeGroupText  CodeDesc  State_ID
-------  -----  -------------  ---------- --------  -------------- --------- ---------
1        AAAA    1             100         Plastic   Plastic Center  NULL      2
3        CCCC    1             101         Steel     Steel Center    NULL      2
```

Comment: Edited with more information

Comment: Edited again with the results

Comment: And is it arbitrary which row you want returned from each group or do you want a specific one?

Comment: It doesn't matter which row is returned just need one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use a subquery to return the `min(codeid)` for each `codegroup` and join this result to your table:

```
select t1.codeid,
    t1.code,
    t1.catalogtype,
    t1.codegroup,
    t1.codetext,
    t1.codegrouptext,
    t1.codedesc,
    t1.state_id
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
    select MIN(codeid) codeid, codegroup
    from yourtable
    group by codegroup
) t2
    on t1.codeid = t2.codeid
    and t1.codegroup = t2.codegroup
```

Comment: Thanks this works I never knew about the subquery. This is a nice bit of SQL thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

In most databases, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by field order by field) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting the first query for MySQL, when you know that it will return results (rows) that are not in the table?

Comment: @ypercube . . . First, I say so in the answer.  Second, the question doesn't say what to do with values when there are multiple rows.  And, third, the question has been modified so it is not about MySQL.

Comment: +1 Your interpretation of the question seems correct following clarification.

Comment: The question had from the start *"... but return all rows related to the values selected."* Advertising an ill-written query does not make it right by admitting it is so.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT field1,field2,max(field3),sum(field4)
FROM table
GROUP BY field1, field2
```

This will give you all distinct field1 and field2's. You cannot get the field3 field directly (with this grouping), since there may be multiple field3's.

Answer (score 0):

if you need just distinct values from a column, i.e. to find a set of unique values in one column, then this code helps you (for sql server at least):

```
select distinct
    columnName
from tableT
```